# Type stability for lists of closures

Tags: julia, type-stability

I'm trying to design some code in Julia which will take a list of user-supplied functions and essentially apply some algebraic operations to them.

It appears that the return value of this list of functions will not be inferred if they are closures, leading to type-unstable code according to @code_warntype.

I tried supplying a return type with the closures but did not seem to be able to find the correct syntax.

Here is an example:

```
functions = Function[x -> x]

function f(u)
    ret = zeros(eltype(u), length(u))

    for func in functions
        ret .+= func(u)
    end

    ret
end
```

Run this:

```
u0 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
@code_warntype f(u0)
```

and obtain

```
Body::Array{Float64,1}
1 ─ %1  = (Base.arraylen)(u)::Int64
│   %2  = $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{Float64,1}, svec(Any, Int64), :(:ccall), 2, Array{Float64,1}, :(%1), :(%1)))::Array{Float64,1}
│   %3  = invoke Base.fill!(%2::Array{Float64,1}, 0.0::Float64)::Array{Float64,1}
│   %4  = Main.functions::Any
│   %5  = (Base.iterate)(%4)::Any
│   %6  = (%5 === nothing)::Bool
│   %7  = (Base.not_int)(%6)::Bool
└──       goto #4 if not %7
2 ┄ %9  = φ (#1 => %5, #3 => %15)::Any
│   %10 = (Core.getfield)(%9, 1)::Any
│   %11 = (Core.getfield)(%9, 2)::Any
│   %12 = (%10)(u)::Any
│   %13 = (Base.broadcasted)(Main.:+, %3, %12)::Any
│         (Base.materialize!)(%3, %13)
│   %15 = (Base.iterate)(%4, %11)::Any
│   %16 = (%15 === nothing)::Bool
│   %17 = (Base.not_int)(%16)::Bool
└──       goto #4 if not %17
3 ─       goto #2
4 ┄       return %3
```

So, how do I make this code type stable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want type-stability for arbitrary functions, you'll have to pass them as a tuple, which allows julia to know in advance which function will be applied at which stage.

```
function fsequential(u, fs::Fs) where Fs<:Tuple
    ret = similar(u)
    fill!(ret, 0)
    return fsequential!(ret, u, fs...)
end

@inline function fsequential!(ret, u, f::F, fs...) where F
    ret .+= f(u)
    return fsequential!(ret, u, fs...)
end
fsequential!(ret, u) = ret

julia> u0 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0

julia> fsequential(u0, (identity, x-> x .+ 1))
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 3.0
 5.0
 7.0
```

If you inspect this with `@code_warntype` you'll see it's inferrable.

`fsequential!` is an example of what is sometimes called "lispy tuple programming" in which you iteratively process one argument at a time until all vararg arguments have been exhausted. It's a powerful paradigm that allows much more flexible inference than a `for`-loop with an array (because it allows Julia to compile separate code for each "loop iteration"). However, it's generally only useful if the number of elements in the container is fairly small, otherwise you end up with insanely long compile times.

The type parameters `F` and `Fs` look unnecessary, but they are designed to force Julia to specialize the code for the particular functions you pass in.

Comment: This is indeed a nice solution for loop unrolling. I have added `@generated` version in my answer for a comparison (they have approximately the same performance).

Comment: Thank you, this is super useful! (Both answers are, actually, so if I could give two checkmarks I would. There is no one solution to this apparently).

Comment: Very nice answer @tholy! I am wandering if your comment regarding the need for the type parameters `F` and `Fs` still applies to the latest Julia versions: I tried to remove them and noticed no difference in terms of type stability or memory allocation. If they actually matter, could you kindly point the section in the Julia manual where this issue is explained? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There are several layers issues in your code (unfortunately to type stability):

1. `functions` is a global variable so fundamentally your code will not be type stable
2. Even if you moved `functions` inside the function definition and it would be a vector the code would still be type unstable, as the container would have abstract eltype (this would remain true even if you removed `Function` prefix before `[` if you had more than one different function)
3. If you changed a vector to tuple (then the collection `functions` would be type stable) the function would still be type unstable, because you use a loop which would not be able to internally infer the return type of `func(u)`

The solution would be to use `@generated` function that would unroll the loop into a sequence of consecutive applications of `func(u)` - then your code would be type stable.

However, in general I think, assuming that `func(u)` is an expensive operation, that the type instability in your code should not be very problematic as in the end you convert the return value of `func(u)` to `Float64` anyway.

**EDIT** A `@generated` version for comparison with what is proposed by Tim Holy.

```
@generated function fgenerated(u, functions::Tuple{Vararg{Function}})
    expr = :(ret = zeros(eltype(u), size(u)))
    for fun in functions.parameters
        expr = :($expr; ret .+= $(fun.instance)(u))
    end
    return expr
end
```

Comment: Good answer, as usual... But, I wonder why all you guys with the brilliant answers never upvote the questions... if it's worth answering, the question is worth an upvote as well, surely‽

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful to know as a general design principle.